# How to return my cursor automatically after an indentation in Python?

Tags: python, vim, syntax, editor, indentation

any code editor knows where to indent in python since python uses `:` as its indent flag, but after completing a code block, we will want our cursor to go back in the last place it was, like this:

```
def test_func():
    print("Here we have an auto indent")
    # but how to

# return, without pressing the backspace key
```

Comment: You can't, since there is no marker for the end of the block other than the dedent itself.  You can have blank lines in indented blocks, so just having a blank line doesn't mean it's the end of the block.

Comment: Try `control` + `enter` ...

Comment: i noticed using `pass` in vim with ycm plugin can do the dedentation for me, can i use `pass` like `end` in Ruby or `}` in C?

Comment: Isn't this question IDE/editor specific? In PyCharm 2016.2, writing `pass` at the end of any function and then pressing `enter` **will** move the cursor to the beginning of the next line.

Comment: `control` + `enter` doesn't work in Atom, what editor are you using?

Comment: yea, it is related to editors, which is why i changed tags

Comment: It is still too broad, as it probably not going to be the same answer for *every* editor on the planet. You should at least mention the editor that *you* are using.

Comment: hmm, you are right.. i just wanted to know if anyone has a solution to this indentation issue, as i tested, vim with ycm also takes `pass` as dedentation flag

Comment: Dedenting after `pass` is a **guess**, an assumption the IDE is making. It usually is the right guess, but it is still just a guess. It isn't possible for an IDE to know when your blocks end because that's what unindenting is *for*.

Comment: thanks. so that's why some editors do the guess while some others don't.. i will take `pass` as `end` then (a place holder, like they said, does no harm anyway)

Comment: @jm33_m0: To answer your question about which editor I use — doesn't matter really; I think the `control` + `enter` behavior is specific to the OS key bindings. Depending on your OS you may have something equivalent ( just a different modifier key perhaps ). In `OS X` for example, control + enter will put the cursor at the beginning of the next line in *almost* any editor unless it's specifically been overridden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it is not possible for an IDE to know when your block is ending in all cases.

The are a few *exceptions* where it is reasonable to *guess* that you wanted to end the current indentation level. E.g. using `pass` to leave a block 'empty' where the Python grammar requires you to use a block, or using `return`, `break` or `continue`, statements that make it impossible for Python to reach the remainder of the indented block.

However, *because* you must un-indent to signal the end of a block in Python, your IDE can't know in all cases when a block ends *either*. You can easily follow a `print()` call with several empty lines, then another line of code at the same indentation level, and it'll still be part of `test_func()` body.

It depends entirely on your editor if they implement auto-indentation rules at all, but any that does, is bound by the same limitations inherent in Python.